# Android GPS Geocoding API limit

Tags: android, gps, geolocation, geocoding

Google maps and geocoding functions have a request limit.

I am trying to use geodecoing in one of the application in Android and as per the below URL :
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Limits

Google geocoding limit is 25000 maps load per day

So is this limit per user or per device or per API key?

Comment: I have not used the service, but the page you linked to says: "Including a key in your request: Enables per-key instead of per-IP-address quota limits." So the limit probably depends on how you are accessing the API. If you are looking for a Geocoding API without request limits, check out [SmartyStreets](https://smartystreets.com/articles/do-maps-verify-addresses).

Answer (score 0):

There is no limitations for the use of geocoding in an Android app, if obviously you are using the Google Location API.

As written by Google:

> The Google Earth API, and native Maps APIs for mobile platforms such
>   as Android and iOS are not affected. Use of the embed feature of
>   Google Maps, and other Google products that offer an embed feature
>   that includes a map, are not affected by these limits.

https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usage_mapload